# How to update status to wrong match characters where portion key charterer not match charterer on signature key?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-function

I work on SQL server 2012 I face issue I cannot update status with not match character where portion key not equal signature key character based on group id .

Group Id Represented as  :
*$*$C$***$**$**$*  (1=*,2=*,3=C,4=***,5=**,6=**,7=*)

```
Signature Key      Group Id  Portion Key      status       Signature Key(group Id 3)       Reason 
*$*$C$***$**$**$*   3          s              wrong              C                         s <> C
```

as row above give me wrong match character on status because group id 3 on signature key  will be
C and portion key is s character so I will update status with wrong match character because s not equal c

Data Sample :

```
Create table #Ref
(
SignatureKey  nvarchar(50),
GroupId int,
PortionKey nvarchar(50),
Status nvarchar(100)
)
insert into #Ref(SignatureKey,GroupId,PortionKey,status)
values
('*$*$C$***$**$**$*',3,'s',NUll),
('*$*$*$FG$*$**$*',4,'F',NUll),
('*$*$*$***$*$D$*',6,'D',NUll),
('*$*$*$***$***$**$*',2,'g',NUll),
('*$**$*$***$L$**$*',5,'f',NUll)
```

Expected Result :

```
Signature Key      Group Id  Portion Key             Status
*$*$C$***$**$**$*   3          s                wrong Match chatterers
*$*$*$FG$*$**$*     4          F                wrong Match chatterers
*$*$*$***$*$D$*     6          D                wrong Match chatterers
*$*$*$***$***$**$*  2          g                wrong Match chatterers
*$**$*$***$L$**$*   5          f                wrong Match chatterers
```

For more explain see Image below :
[image: Not match portion key based on group id]

I Make this function but can't know how to call it :

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_split_string]
(
    @string    nvarchar(max),
    @delimiter nvarchar(max)
)

RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
(
    SELECT 
      --ROW_NUMBER ( ) over(order by (select 0))                            AS id     --  intuitive, but not correect
        Split.a.value('let $n := . return count(../*[. << $n]) + 1', 'int') AS id
      , Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')                                 AS value
    FROM
    (
        SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(@string, @delimiter, '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String
    ) AS a
    CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS Split(a)
)
```

How to call it according to my sample

```
select * from [dbo].[fn_split_string]('*$*$C$***$**$**$*','$') pc
```

Comment: Would you be able to tell us what you have tried so far? At a very high level, you will need to create a string splitting function which will split [SignatureKey] using tokenizer '$'. You will then need to match char specified by position [Groupid] with [PortionKey].

Comment: yes this is actually what I need

Comment: can you tell me How i do it I use SQL server 2012

Comment: see update post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have borrowed a string split function from online (Link: https://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=50648)

The function returns a table of split string. For example, if I run

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Split('*$**$*$***$L$**$*','$')
```

Returned result is:

[image]

Once you have your function to split a string, you can use CROSS APPLY to run it against all rows in your table.

```
declare @Ref table
(
SignatureKey  nvarchar(50),
GroupId int,
PortionKey nvarchar(50),
Status nvarchar(100)
)
insert into @Ref(SignatureKey,GroupId,PortionKey,status)
values
('*$*$C$***$**$**$*',3,'s',NUll),
('*$*$*$FG$*$**$*',4,'F',NUll),
('*$*$*$***$*$D$*',6,'D',NUll),
('*$*$*$***$***$**$*',2,'g',NUll),
('*$**$*$***$L$**$*',5,'f',NUll)

select r.*, f.* 
,case
when r.PortionKey = f.Data then 'match' else 'not match' 
end
from @Ref r
cross apply
dbo.Split(r.SignatureKey,'$') f where r.GroupId = f.Id
```

The result set is:

[image]

Hope this is helpful.